# What's the best way to loop over an array in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

So I have a JSON file that has a **departures** array within it. I'd like to loop over each bus line and display them in div's like so:

```
<div class="bus">
    <div class="line">departure.line</div>
    <div class="direction">departure.direction</div>
    <div class="time">departure.time</div>
</div>
```

Each incoming bus has it's own bus div with all the related information inside it. I've gotten as far as displaying one of these, however I'm not sure how to iterate over them and display them in the correct places.

I'm open to utilizing vanilla JavaScript or jQuery.

Here's a jsfiddle with the array I want to iterate over: http://jsfiddle.net/tmm7b31w/

Comment: Sounds like you need a forEach ;)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You need a foreach loop to simply go through the elements. See sample below:

```
$.each(item, function(index1, item1){
    var divContent = 
        '<div class="line">' + item1.line + '</div>' +
        '<div class="direction">' + item1.direction + '</div>' +
        '<div class="time">' + item1.aimed_departure_time + '</div>';

        $('#container').append(divContent);
});
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tmm7b31w/4/).

Comment: You should minimize access to the dom. Create the full html to append and append it at the end (after loops) to be more effective

Comment: you can do better -> [your fiddler updated](https://jsfiddle.net/royto/zqvbs6br/)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use a for each, like this:

HTML

```
<div class="bus prototype">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="direction"></div>
    <div class="time"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (with jQuery)

```
var parent = $('body');
var prototype = $('.bus.prototype');

$.each(data.departures, function(index, departure) {
    var bus_div = prototype.clone();

    bus_div.find('.line').text(departure.line);
    //etc...

    parent.append(bus_div);
});
```

You could also do it with a vanilla JavaScript for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.departures.length; i++) {
    var departure = data.departures[i];

    var bus_div = prototype.clone();

    bus_div.find('.line').text(departure.line);
    //etc...

    parent.append(bus_div);
}
```